# any feature or webpart in sharepoint 2007 that can show such filter results

Tags: sharepoint

in sharepoint i have two lists

one list is authors
other list is books

the authors list has one of the fields called authorname. in books list one column is authors . which creating an item in books the authors column is filled by selecting the authorname field of list authors ( lookup )

is there any webpart of feature available in sharepoint server 2007 in which if we select any authorname and do a filter the items in author list with that author name appear and the items in books with that author appear as results.

or a way in which something like this can be developed using sharepoint designer ?

Any help at all will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misundestood your question but this can be done out of the box (OOTB) in all versions of SharePoint using web part connections.

This gives an example (the screenshots are from 2003, but its basically the same in 2007)

- [Web Part Connections](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/planner/planner-manual?p=faq/webpartconnections/faq_webpartconnections.htm)

This example has a list of Building Projects (like your Books list) and a list of Contractors (like your Authors list). Building Projects has a lookup column to the Contractors list.

When you connect the web parts together you are setting up a filter provider (Contractors) and a filter consumer (Building Projects).

So when you click on a particular contractor only the building projects assigned to them are displayed.

[Microsoft have a guide to web part Connections](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100241051033.aspx) - but its a bit of a hard read I think.